# Applying conditional comparative (lt, eq, gt) expressions for items that are don't exist in the DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

My objective is to insert an item in a DynamoDB table if it does not exist already and one of attributes has a minimum value.

The hash-key is `productId` and rage-key is `locationId`. The attribute that should have a minimum value if `price`. The minimum value is `0.0`.

e.g.

- if an item with primary key that does not exist in the table, has `price` as `10.0`, it will be inserted. But in case that item has `price` as `0.0`, it should be rejected.
- if the item already existed and the `price` was `0.0`, I want to update the `price` to `0.0`.

The code that I am trying to use is:

```
PrimaryKey primaryKey = new PrimaryKey(
    "productId", productId,
    "locationId", locationId
);
Item newItem = new Item()
    .withPrimaryKey(primaryKey)
    .withDouble("price", 0.0d);
PutItemSpec putItemSpec = new PutItemSpec()
    .withItem(newItem)
    .withConditionExpression("attribute_not_exists(productId) AND attribute_not_exists(locationId) AND (price > :lowerBound)")
    .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withNumber(":lowerBound", 0.0d));
PutItemOutcome putItemOutcome = table.putItem(putItemSpec);
```

When I run this I get `ConditionalCheckFailedException`. In order to isolate the issue I tried breaking the condition into

- `attribute_not_exists(productId) AND attribute_not_exists(locationId)`
- `price > :lowerBound`

I found that `attribute_not_exists(productId) AND attribute_not_exists(locationId)` by itself work fine.

`price > :lowerBound` fails when used by itself. I tried values like `0.0`, `18000.0` and even `-2.0`. They all fail due to `ConditionalCheckFailedException`.

I wonder if my understanding about the condition-expressions in incorrect? Is it even possible to apply comparative expressions to items that do no exist yet?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing.  Specifically, when you say "if the item already existed and the price was 0.0, I want to update the price to 0.0".  Why would you update 0 to 0?  Isn't the outcome the same if you did nothing at all?

Answer (score 0):

Condition expressions in DynamoDB describe the expected item in DynamoDB *before* the write. There's no need to use a condition expression to describe the expectations of the value you're writing, because you can just validate those expectations yourself before doing the write.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do know the value of `price` before any write operation. But I do not know if the item exists in the table.

Also I think i missed one point: if the item already existed and the `price` was `0.0`, I want to overwrite the `price` with `0.0`.

Comment: As an alternative I could also perform a `GetItem` call and perform the validation? but that would mean 1 read for every write.

Comment: @AnimeshPandey: Re: "if the item already existed and the price was 0.0, I want to overwrite the price with 0.0": I don't understand; overwriting 0.0 with 0.0 is a no-op; if that's the update, then why do you even care whether the write goes through?